# Spring RestTemplate, GsonHttpMessageConverter

Tags: java, spring, gson

given JSON

```
{"news" : [ {...}, {...}, {...} ] }
```

the array contains custom objects, which I already declared as POJOs. Want I simply want to map my custom objects by keypath "news".

```
restTemplate.exchange(URI + "/news/{limit}/", HttpMethod.GET, CustomObject[].class, 10)
```

throws an exception, because this JSON is expected

```
[ {...}, {...}, {...}]
```

Is there a way to configure RestTemplate to match my needs?

Regards

**Update:**

```
restTemplate.exchange(URI + "/news/{limit}/", HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, JsonElement.class,10).getBody().getAsJsonObject().get("news");
CustomObject[] result = gson.fromJson(body, CustomObject[].class);
```

This snippet works but is there a cleaner way? For my suprise mapping to `JSONObject` doesn't even worked, JSONElement did the job at the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'll add my update in here to close this question. If someone can provide a cleaner solution I'll be happy to accept it:

```
restTemplate.exchange(URI + "/news/{limit}/", HttpMethod.GET, requestEntity, JsonElement.class,10).getBody().getAsJsonObject().get("news");
CustomObject[] result = gson.fromJson(body, CustomObject[].class);
```

This snippet works but is there a cleaner way? For my suprise mapping to JSONObject doesn't even worked, JSONElement did the job at the end.